# Crash report не создается на айпаде.

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios

Достоверно известно, что приложение вылетало на устройстве.
При подключении к компьютеру, икскодовский Organizer не «видит» ни одного крэшлога. В директории

```
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<имя девайса>
```

только два подозрительных файла `aggregated-2010-11-15.crash` и `aggregated-2010-11-17.crash`, внутри которых ничего интересного, и это даже не крэшлоги.

Почему такое может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась так: на компьютере разработчика почему-то было отключено копирование крэшлогов для конкретного устройства. Чтобы включить обратно, нужно было произвести следующие действия в iTunes:

1. Правой кнопкой по устройству, выбрать «Reset Warnings» и выполнить синхронизацию.
2. При синхронизации iTunes спросит: «You can help Apple improve its products and user support by having you iPhone automatically send Apple information from time to time about how it's working and how you use it.» Нужно ответить «ОК» и «Do not ask me again» и впредь крэшлоги будут копироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно для начала включить core dump's

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Для того, чтобы сделать создание дампов возможным

Если используете csh, то

```
limit coredumpsize unlimited
```

Просто по умолчанию лимиит на коредамп - 0, поэтому он никогда не создаётся при падении.

Comment: Где включить? В маке или на айпаде?

Comment: Это надо делать на том устройстве, на котором выполняется приложение и на котором оно крешится.